# Restore mysql database tables in a different database without tables lock

Tags: mysql, import, innodb

I have readed a lot of posts about dump databases without tables lock to avoid to lock other queries, but in this case I need to dump some InnoDB tables (about 10) from a database without activity to import in another database with a lot of activity and I don't want to lock the target database while import is running. The final dump is about 5GB (one table has about 80 million rows).

The new database doesn't have the tables created, will be created and filled during the import.

In all my tests the target database crashes*, even without any queries accessing the new tables.

- the target database is completely locked on dump import. The new tables are not used yet, but the MySQL is totally locked and can't respond to any other query to any other table.

How is the best way to import a large SQL without any lock?

The dump is a simple `mysqldump > file.sql` and import with `mysql < file.sql`

This is a file example:

```sql
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.30, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: database-target
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `table_one`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_one`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `table_one` (
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `table_one`
--

LOCK TABLES `table_one` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `table_one` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `table_one` VALUES (XXXXXXXX);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `table_one` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Dump the structure only (mysqldump.exe). Divide it (by hands) to tables+PK only dump and other objects (indices, FKs, procedures, triggers and so on) dump. Dump data only as CSV files set (SELECT INTO OUTFILE, separate file for each table). Restore tables dump. Restore data (LOAD DATA).Restore other objects. For to provide consistency you need to lock data access only on data_to_CSV dumping step.

Comment: _In all my tests the target database crashes_ Please explain how it crashes

Comment: If you are dumping from a database without any activity, locks a surely irrelevant! If the tables **do not exists in the new database** then nothing can be looking at the tables until you create and fill them. So again locking seems almost irrelevant, but you could in case an eagle eyes user see's you creating them! But locking them will not be an issue as nobody could be using a table that does not exists :) I could be missing something here, but again I would be interested in knowing the reason for the crash

Comment: @RiggsFolly the target database is completely locked on dump import. The new tables are not used yet, but the MySQL is totally locked and can't respond to any other query to any other table.

Comment: _the target database is completely locked on import_ Why? Is that something you do, or do you think the Import process is doing that? In that case how are you importing?

Comment: I have added a mysqldump SQL example. Thanks!

Comment: So that wil lock each NEW table as it is loaded, It will not lock all the other tables

Comment: Yes, it's why I don't understand why the database is totally locked when I only import this tables...

Comment: How is this TOTAL lock manifesting itself? AND what is the Crash error you mention#

Comment: With the `mysql` command I can not load into the server console. it stucks in the server welcome message `Welcome to the MySQL monitor...`

Comment: That does not mean the database is locked. I am not sure what it does mean, but it does not mean normal website access is being stoppped, I assume the data is used on a website?

Comment: Did you try running the mysql terminal processor from another PC/Device. i.e. not the one you are running the Import from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249106/discussion-between-lito-and-riggsfolly).